# Cmake link library target link error

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glut, glew

Hi I have problem with linkg Glfw and other libraries using cmake.
From command line i compile like this

```
g++ main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglfw
```

But I wanted to use cmake for compiling. I tried to use target_linkg_libraries but this produce error

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (target_link_libraries):   Cannot
>   specify link libraries for target "GL" which is not built by this
>   project.

I tried do this using add definitions. I dont see error but this don't link libraries.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (test)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(
    -lGL
    -lGLU
    -lGLEW
    -lglfw
)

add_executable(test.out
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(GL GLU GLEW glfw)
```

Comment: `ADD_DEFINITIONS` is for extra defines not for libraries, try `add_libraries()` then.

Comment: unknown command add_libraries

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The syntax for `target_link_libraries` is:

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable_name libraries_list)
```

And you don't have to add `add_definition` statements (`target_link_libraries` adds this options)

There are also some useful variables provided by OpenGL and GLEW packages.

Your CMakeLists.txt should be like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (test)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(test ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

One important detail to keep in mind is to place the `target_link_libraries` **after** the `add_executable` (or `add_library`) line.

Comment: An important detail is to place `target_link_libraries` **after** the `add_executable` **and** `find_package` lines, so all linked components are known.

Comment: .. or, if you are making a library, to place it after `add_library`.

Comment: How do I know if the name is PKGNAME_INCLUDE_DIR or PKGNAME_INCLUDE_DIRS ?