# Migration from Makefile to CMake: -I

Tags: makefile, cmake, gem5

We have an old compilation script in Makefile and would like to start using CMake.
Does anyone perhaps know what would be the equivalent of -I from Makefile in CMake?

This is the concrete line:
"-I gem5-stable/util/m5 gem5-stable/util/m5/m5op_x86.S"

Comment: This is a trivial question. First you have to understand what `-l` option does. Search `"-l" compiler option`. Then you search `link cmake`. And the first result is [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Sorry, but it wasn't trivial to me.

Comment: Excuse me Antonio, but your comments are unrelated and not constructive.

Comment: Undeniably: it has been removed by a moderator. I was just showing how you could have solved the problem by yourself, with a correct use of google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to see your actual CMake file, but you may want to take a look at [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: Thank you. In the combination with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478088/cmake-link-library-target-link-error I got exactly I wanted.